# How does neutral minions HP and damage scale throughout the game?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

With the latest patch, the core's shield, regen and HP were modified, I'm wondering about the stats of other elements in the game, such as mercenaries, doubloon camps minions, minions in the mines, etc.

I'm wondering if any data or information was published regarding neutral minions stats like HP and damage dealt, as it would greatly help me to know how it scales as a Nova player to clear camps and such.

Comment: I personally would like seeing minion HP as well to better optimize gameplay. However, Heroes seems to minimize the number-crunching. For example, the character stats screen ('C' hotkey in game) shows how little there is to manage. No armor, no penetration, no real 'detail'.

Comment: i've made an edit to the answer, you should check it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some data mining results out there about such stats. One of the dataminers, [u/Ahli](http://www.reddit.com/user/Ahli) has a few about similar stats on reddit. I could only found one item regarding your question.

- Knight Camp's Mage's life reduced to 1000 (+60 per minute) from 1300 (+78 per minute), magic missile ability's damage increased to 60 (+3 per minute) (+100% damage vs summoned) from 40 (+ 4.8 per minute), weapon damage increased to 20 (+5 per minute) from 20 (+ 1.6 per minute). There is no increase during first minute, but it's scaling up to minute 60. After 20 minutes, the mages that you have captured receive higher stats per minute: +5 magic missile damage, +8 weapon damage, +105 life instead of the other values.

---

There is no official information about these numbers yet, however I've managed to find [an article written about the neutral creeps](http://2p.com/5498801_1/Heroes-of-the-Storm-Neutral-Minions-Preview-by-JaminNoob.htm). Even though it is slightly outdated (April 1), It might be a starting point for you.

**'Edit**: Asked u/Ahli for merc stats, [and he delivered](http://www.reddit.com/r/heroesofthestorm/comments/2p0c6k/datamined_mercenary_stats/). [Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhppro252sutl3q/mercenaries.txt?dl=0).

Comment: It shows how the stats scale according to time, which is interesting. I though they would scale depending on both teams level or experience. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks again. Now that I have the base and scaling stats for each of them, it'll be way easier to quickly clear camps when passing by as Nova!